# Is there a way to reset all today extensions (widgets) on a device?

Tags: ios, iphone, today-extension

I'm developing a today extension (widget) and noticed that it's often necessary to get a clean state if something has been changed. But the today view doesn't correctly reset the extension widget, when I run a new build of the extension. Also not when running on the extension target from Xcode. Sometimes I also get 'can't show data' or something similar.

The only way seems to be to delete the app from the device and re-run installation from Xcode. This is a pain because I need to input the test data by hand each time...

Question: is there a way to reset the today view in total on a device? I'm not interested in the same thing on a simulator, I need to do it on a device.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the easiest way is to cold start the device (if you don't want to erase the app).